# Enthought Canopy does not start up even after successful and previous use on Windows 8.1 (x64) - how to fix?

Tags: python, windows, enthought, canopy

I installed Canopy a couple of days ago. I started it up, and explored it a little -- in other words, it opened up just fine.

Today, however, it hangs on its loading screen: [image: Canopy loading screen]

After a long while of waiting (more than an hour) and still nothing happening, I became impatient and clicked on the Canopy loading screen, and got the following: [image: Canopy is not responding]

I have tried to make sure that PYTHONPATH, etc. are cleared out. I have also uninstalled and then re-installed the program. What else might I try, and what might the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, sorry to hear it @user89, and thanks for the report. This could seem like a corruption of some files. Please have a look to this knowledge base article about fully uninstalling Canopy from your system and installing again:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-Canopy

Please comment on this article again if that didn't help.